# Service Bus - Teste de desempenho com Service Bus

Tags: jmeter, microsoft-azure

Eu preciso fazer testes de desempenho no Service Bus da Microsoft. Estou usando jmeter para teste de desempenho, entendo que o Jmeter pode ser configurado para colocar mensagens, alguém sabe como posso configurar a ferramenta e se esta e melhor ferramente para este tipo de teste?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode utilizar o próprio serviço da Microsoft Application Insights com Azure Functions para fazer telemetrias do serviço, já segui este link abaixo para este tipo de teste. Qualquer dúvida só falar!

http://www.azurefieldnotes.com/2017/06/04/azure-service-bus-monitoring-and-alerting-using-azure-function-and-application-insights/

Comment: Existe alguma forma de utilizar o Jmeter para estes testes? Ou apanas as próprias ferramentas do Azure.

Comment: com jmeter não sei se é possível, mas dei uma fuçada e encontrei alguns links: https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/test/performance-testing/getting-started/get-started-jmeter-test https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37222685/performance-testing-of-microsoft-service-bus